# Check whether an Excel cell contains an item of an array

Tags: arrays, excel, powershell

I have an Excel file, and there is a column in it, which contains short descriptions. I have an array, which contains numbers. I have to detect if a cell contains any number of the array or not.

My code looks something like this:

```
$CurrentCell = $openedworksheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).Value()
$Array='1', '2', '3', '4'

$a = 0
foreach ($numbers in $Array) {
    if ($numbers -match $currentCell) {
        $a = 1
    }
    if ($a -eq 0) {
       Write-Host $currentCell
    }
}
```

I've tried many variations, but didn't get the desired result.

Comment: `if($Array.Contains($currentCell))`

Comment: the cells contain text too, and the number is only a little part of it.

Comment: Change the $array values to be like '*1*', '*2*', etc. Then use -Like instead of -match. Also move the second if out of the foreach

Comment: With things like this, I'd suggested figuring it out first directly in Excel, so that it's responding like you want it to, and then Google how to "translate" that specific command or method into PS For example, ***Excel has dozens of ways to check if one string contains another***.  Which you should use depends on your individual case. **You've already been given a solution that answered your question**, and then you added more criteria to your original problem. *Use Excel to figure out your exact question first, and then Google from there*.  If you can't find an solution anywhere then [edit].

Comment: `Value` is a property, not a method, so remove the parentheses from `.Value()`. Then try `if ($numbers | ? {"$currentCell".Contains($_)}) {Write-Host $currentCell}`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you a lot for your help guys. The final solution is:

```
$CurrentCell = $openedworksheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).text
$Array='1', '2', '3', '4'


foreach ($numbers in $Array) {
     if($CurrentCell.Contains($number)){
           write-host $currentCell
     }
}
```

:)